# Best option available to allow empty string with a Regex

Tags: regex

I have a Regex to validate a password: at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and one special character:

```
^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:-_])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:-_]+
```

But I also want to allow empty because I will validate it in another way.

So I tried to options:

```
^((?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:-_])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:-_]+)*$
```

NOTE: I wrapped the Regex in () and added *$ at the end;

Or the following:

```
^$|(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:-_])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:-_]+
```

NOTE: Added $| at start ...

What is the best approach? One of these 2 or some other?

Comment: I tried your approach before but when I use ^[A-Za-z0-9]*|$ to allow only alphanumeric and empty this allows Spaces and I have no idea why

Comment: Use an optional non-capturing group around the whole pattern between the anchors `^(?:...)?$`

Comment: `^$|^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:_-])[\w$@$!%*?&,;.:-]+$` should work fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do you mean: ^(?:(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:-_])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:-_]+)?$

Comment: @anubhava why the $ after the + at the end? Would $| at start be enough?

Comment: I think you asked another question with simple regex. I've already posted an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a regex matching *at least something*, but not the whole string, you need to use an alternation with `$`:

```
^(?:(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:_-])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:_-]+|$)
^^^^                                                                                        ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO1mG3/2). Look:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - An alternation group start

  - `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:_-])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:_-]+` - match this
  - `|` - or...
  - `$` - end of string.
- `)` - end of the alternation

If you had a pattern that matched the whole string (say, `^\d+\s+\w+$` to match strings like `12 Apr`), and you would like to also match an empty string, you could just enclose with an optional pattern:

```
^(?:\d+\s+\w+)?$
 ^^^         ^^
```

Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d+\s+\w+)?` - one or zero sequences of 1+ digtis followed with 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ alphanumerics/underscores
- `$` - end of string